# Using .split() to add sentences (with commas) into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, split

I am adding sentences to an array, but I need the array items to be split in a way that will take into account sentences with commas in them.

Currently I am using `String.split(",");` but it splits a single sentence into 2 different array items if the sentence has a comma in it. Ideally I would like to do something simple like ignore commas that are followed by whitespace. `", "`.

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and expected output?

Comment: I would Google 'javascript regex' and start from there. Regular Expressions permit the type of pattern matching it appears you're looking to implement. That being said, you should show some of your work.

Comment: Why don't you use any other common delimiter instead of comma?

Comment: Input would be something like:

This is a sentence, that has a comma., This is a sentence, that has a comma., This is a sentence, that has a comma., This is a sentence, that has a comma.,

Currently it would output:
[This is a sentence]
[that has a comma.]
[This is a sentence]
[that has a comma.]

Ideally it would output as:

[This is a sentence, that has a comma.]
[This is a sentence, that has a comma.]
[This is a sentence, that has a comma.]

Comment: The object starts off as an array, turns into a string once added to sessonStorage, and then I want to turn it back into an array on page load. If that makes sense, so the comma is already included as a divider.

Comment: Based on example that you provided, you can use simply `str.split(".,")`. No need for regex if lost dot does not matter

Comment: This preserve dot notation: `str.split(".,").map(s => s + '.')`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript `.split()` can accept a RegExp as argument. So what you want to achieve is fairly simple with a [negative look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```js
var s = "I'm a sentence,I'm another sentence, but with a comma,the last sentence";

console.log( s.split( /,(?! )/ ) )
```

That being said, you shouldn't use a comma as a delimiter if your sentence contains commas. You should solve your problem at the root: where does the string come from and why is it a string (and not an array)? Unfortunately, we cannot help you more than that with the information provided.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will do, this should provide a temp fix. Thanks!

Comment: @CoreySizemore After reading your comments, I saw that you are using `sessionStorage`. Take a look at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Example_of_using_JSON.stringify()_with_localStorage). It will solve the `split/join` problem. You just need to stringify/parse the array.

Comment: @bigless Answers should not be base on comments but on the question itself. "*I would like to do something simple like ignore commas that are followed by whitespace. ", "*". Also, since the OP said "*this should provide a temp fix*", we can *assume* it works. Rule of thumbs, you can edit a question, but not a comment. Also, note the answer was posted before the comments.

Comment: Requirement was to split sentences. Usually, sentence delimiter is dot/q.mark/e.mark.

Comment: @bigless Look, this answer helped (and maybe solved) OP's problem. So I'll let it as is since it's what OP asked for (*ignore commas that are followed by whitespace. ", "*). But if you think I'm wrong, feel free to post your own answer, that's what this site is about.

Comment: I downvoted and also commented why. Many others don't do that so please don't blame me.

Comment: @bigless Please, do not think I'm blaming you. I already guessed you downvoted and I'm explaining my point of view. Still, downvote means you are disagreeing with my answer, which is ok, hence why I told you to post your answer. I have no grudge against you, so I promise I won't rage-downvote :) I just do not think my answer is wrong. That being said, have a good day!

Comment: My answer is within question's comments. I believe that your post helped, but it does not mean thats right answer to question in general. Have a nice day too.